# UI-Bootstrap Collapse doesn't reset on new route

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Working example: http://executionists.com (view in mobile viewport to see the problem)

I'm using the collapse directive from UI Bootstrap and it works great to toggle my menu on/off. However, when I click a menu item, I'm routed to a new view (which is what it should do) but then the menu stays open. It actually flashes for a second as it appears to be collapsing but then springs back open and wont collapse until manually done.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-4"></i>
</button>

<div class="container mobile-menu visible-xs collapse" collapse="isCollapsed">
  <a ng-href="#/about">About</a>
</div>
```

In the relevant controller, I simply set a default state:

```
$scope.isCollapsed = true;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: adding **$('.col-1').click(function(){$(this).toggle();});** in jquery function should work i guess!

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: I see you are using Angular for rendering your page, the problem is that page is render again, its stays on same page

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I see you have some function collapseMenu(), please write it here

Comment: I literally just removed it. But it was $scope.collapseMenu = function () { $scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed; } All the Angular code is found in js/compiled.min.js for review. I have been messing with this for a day now and cannot for the life of me get the toggle to function programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this if I understand that this is want you need

```
  $("div.container.mobile-menu.visible-xs.collapse div.row div.col-1 ul a").click(function() {
          if (window.location.hash) {
              $('.mobile-menu').height(0); //change the menu to be 'Hidden'
          }
  });
```

**UPDATE**

```
$("div.container.mobile-menu.visible-xs.collapse div.row div.col-1 ul a").click(function() {
    $('.mobile-menu').toggle(function() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            $('button.btn.btn-default').click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! This does introduce one little quirk, however. Once you've selected a menu option, the menu disappears, however, it now requires two clicks to get the menu to open up again. Any idea there?

Comment: It will be easy to make working fiddle, try to make it, because i have to look all your code, make simple fiddle what you need and i will help you